# Codewars Runtime Error

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge

I am currently trying to solve the problem "Is my friend cheating?" on Codewars. The Text are the Details to the Problem:

> A friend of mine takes the sequence of all numbers from 1 to n (where
> n > 0).
>
> Within that sequence, he chooses two numbers, a and b.
>
> He says that the product of a and b should be equal to the sum of all
> numbers in the sequence, excluding a and b.
>
> Given a number n, could you tell me the numbers he excluded from the
> sequence? The function takes the parameter: n (n is always strictly
> greater than 0) and returns an array or a string (depending on the
> language) of the form:
>
> ```
> [(a, b), ...] or [[a, b], ...] or {{a, b}, ...} or or [{a, b}, ...]
> ```
>
> with all (a, b) which are the possible removed numbers in the sequence
> 1 to n.
>
> `[(a, b), ...] or [[a, b], ...] or {{a, b}, ...} or ...` will be
> sorted in increasing order of the "a".
>
> It happens that there are several possible (a, b). The function
> returns an empty array (or an empty string) if no possible numbers are
> found which will prove that my friend has not told the truth! (Go: in
> this case return nil).

Examples:

```
removNb(26) should return [(15, 21), (21, 15)]
or
removNb(26) should return { {15, 21}, {21, 15} }
or
removeNb(26) should return [[15, 21], [21, 15]]
or
removNb(26) should return [ {15, 21}, {21, 15} ]
or
removNb(26) should return "15 21, 21 15"
```

or

```
in C:
removNb(26) should return  {{15, 21}{21, 15}} tested by way of strings.
Function removNb should return a pointer to an allocated array of Pair pointers, each 
one also allocated.
```

My Code I tried to solve the Problem with:

```
def removNb(n):
    liste = [i+1 for i in range(n)]
    result = []
    for k in range(n):
        for t in range(k,n):
            m,n = liste[k], liste[t]
            if m * n == sum(liste)-(m+n):
                result.append((m, n))
                result.append((n, m)) 
    return result
```

This solution is working, but appently not enough optimised.

Does anyone have an idea how to optimize the Code further.

Comment: Your title must describe what the code does, not the problem you are experiencing.  "Runtime Error" sounds like the code doesn't work, which would mean the post is "off topic" for this site.  You want to use the `time-limit-exceeded` **tag** instead!  Please edit your post.

Comment: think about expressing it as a mathematical equation - can this help?

Answer (score 2):

**Improving your brute-force solution**. Your current approach will time out
because it conducts an exhaustive search. Nonetheless, it's still instructive
to think about improvements. (1) The question is framed in terms of `a` and
`b`, both within an inclusive range from `1` through `n`, but your code renames
those values to `m` and `n`. The latter is particularly confusing, because now
you're dealing with two meanings for `n` within the same function. Unless you
have a good reason to modify terminology, stick with the conventions already
established. That reduces likelihood of confusion as you translate mentally
from the problem text to your code or as you discuss with others. (2) You don't
need an actual list at all (your `liste` variable). Python ranges are
lightweight objects that have many useful properties for this problem: not only
can we use them to drive the iteration, but we can ask a range for its sum. (3)
Speaking of the sum, don't compute it repeatedly: it never changes, so do it
outside the critical loop. (4) Ranges use a stop value, which means they are
non-inclusive on the upper end, which means you need to your ranges to go to `n + 1`, not `n`. (4) Perhaps I misunderstood the problem, but I think that `a`
and `b` are not supposed to be equal, so the inner loop should start on `a + 1`. (5) Again, maybe I misunderstood, but I think the results need to be sorted
on `a`. Your method of appending the results will disturb that sort order, so
you need to return a sorted list:

```
# A better brute-force approach.
def remov_nb(n):
    n1 = n + 1
    rng = range(1, n1)
    tot = sum(rng)
    result = []
    for a in rng:
        for b in range(a + 1, n1):
            if a * b == tot - a - b:
                result.append([a, b])
                result.append([b, a]) 
    return sorted(result)
```

**Intuition for a faster approach**. We have our primary constraint: `a * b == tot - a - b`. We know the total and can treat it as a constant, but we're
still in a seemingly hopeless situation: we have two unknowns (`a` and `b`) but
only a single equation. But what if we adjust our perspective a bit. We already
have a working brute-force solution based on two for-loops (an `O(n*n)`
algorithm). Our goal isn't to perform a miracle (e.g., solve the problem
instantly the way one might do in an algebra assignment); it's to figure out a better algorithm. An `O(n)` algorithm would be good enough. So let's assume
that we cannot avoid the outer for-loop and then **re-examine our constraint
equation within that context**.

```
# Constraint:
a * b == tot - a - b

# Within the A-loop, we can treat A as a constant and do algebra:
a * b + b   == tot - a
b * (a + 1) == tot - a
b           == (tot - a) / (a + 1)
```

**Compute B directly within the A-loop**. Using that equation, we can omit the
inner loop. Of course, if we just derive B from a calculation, it might violate
the rules of the problem, so we need to apply any remaining conditions before
storing an A-B pair:

```
def remov_nb(n):
    # Same as before.
    rng = range(1, n + 1)
    tot = sum(rng)
    result = []
    for a in rng:

        # Compute B. The division will produce a float.
        bf = (tot - a) / (a + 1)
        b = int(bf)

        # Apply the rest of the constraints.
        if b in rng and b != a and b == bf:
            result.append([a, b])

    # As a side benefit, no sorting required.
    return result
```

Comment: The next improvement might come from using `(a+1)*(b+1)=tot+1`, so you would need to find the factors of `tot+1`.

Comment: @Teepeemm Very good idea. Am I correct in thinking that would produce an algorithm in the `O(n**0.5)` territory ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38817866/55857)).

Comment: @FMc Do you mean `O(tot**.5)` or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @KellyBundy Right, which is interesting, because `tot = (n^2 + n) / 2`.

Comment: @FMc That approach would give you `O(tot**.5)=O(n)`.  More generally,  you could take the prime factorization of `tot+1` and turn the formula from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295465/147357 into a generator for factors of `tot+1`.  I think all of that would still be `O(n)` in the worst case, but faster in the average case (not sure how much faster).  Another thing would be that since we need `a ≤ n`, then `b > n/2` and vice verse.